# xpath to grab outer elements in addition to inner elements that match

Tags: xml, xpath

I have XML that looks something like this:

```
<suite>
    <case> <name>test A1</name> <status>pass</status> </case>
    <case> <name>test A2</name> <status>pass</status> </case>
    <case> <name>test A3</name> <status>pass</status> </case>
    <suiteInfo>this suite...</suiteInfo>
    <suiteInfo>..only pass</suiteInfo>
</suite>
<suite>
    <case> <name>test B1</name> <status>pass</status> </case>
    <case> <name>test B2</name> <status>FAILED</status> </case>
    <case> <name>test B3</name> <status>pass</status> </case>
    <suiteInfo>we had a...</suiteInfo>
    <suiteInfo>failing test!</suiteInfo>
</suite>
<suite>
    <case> <name>test C1</name> <status>pass</status> </case>
    <case> <name>test C2</name> <status>pass</status> </case>
    <case> <name>test C3</name> <status>pass</status> </case>
    <suiteInfo>foo</suiteInfo>
    <suiteInfo>bar</suiteInfo>
</suite>
```

I am only interested in any suites that had failing tests, I would love to somehow extract the failing test **and** the suiteInfo that goes with it.  So it could return something like:

```
<suite>
    <case> <name>test B2</name> <status>FAILED</status> </case>
    <suiteInfo>we had a...</suiteInfo>
    <suiteInfo>failing test!</suiteInfo>
</suite>
```

(And possibly any other suites that had a failing case).

I have been using this xpath:

```
xpath=//suite/case[status=%27FAILED%27]
```

but it leaves out the <suiteInfo> tags that are inside the <suite> but outside the <case> that triggers it.

It is important to not get all the passing cases, because the interface then is very slow (this is through Jenkins).  If I end up getting all of the <suite> and <suiteInfo> but skip out of getting the <case> that pass, I suppose that would also work (in other words, any <suite> with no failing <case> would just have the <suiteInfo>)

Answer (score 0):

I estimate that you cannot get the desired output with XPath alone. You'll need XSLT or something else to reproduce the `<suite>` elements. You can only approximate the desired result, for example with this

1. XPath-1.0 expression (returns the elements in document order)

   ```
    //suite/case[status='FAILED']|//suite[case/status='FAILED']/suiteInfo
   ```
2. XPath-2.0 expression

   ```
    //suite[./case/status='FAILED']/(./case[status='FAILED']|suiteInfo)
   ```

Output in both cases is:

```
<case>
   <name>test B2</name>
   <status>FAILED</status>
</case>
<suiteInfo>we had a...</suiteInfo>
<suiteInfo>failing test!</suiteInfo>
```

Comment: What if there is more than one suite with a failing case?

Comment: I had tested this scenario and the other failed tests are appended in document order. Unfortunately not encapsulated or delimited in/by a `<suite>` element.